# Many dependent combo boxes used as filter

Tags: usability, combobox

I have 6 combox boxes used as filter for a data table. Each combobox is filled with many values. (100-1000)

[image]

If user select a value in a combox, the other comboxes should constraint the "selectable" values. If user select *age* and *city* then *streets* and *names* have much less values to choose. But if user want to find some specifical name, say Bob, he must then unselect *age* and *city* first. Is it not confusing ? What can be done to improve usability ?

**EDIT**:

The values in filters control data in a data table below.

[image]

The real data and filter have another values and column names. (As id, names, layouts and so on...)
It is a part of web enterpise application and not intended to be used as global web site.

Comment: What is this used for? Can you give us some context behind the application you're trying to create?

Comment: @Majo0od I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of easy ways to improve the usability in a UI like this are:

#### Let users search, not just scroll

You mentioned that your dropdowns have a lot of values. Implementing something like the 'Standard Select' at http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ is a great way to help users avoid tedious scrolling.

#### Make it easy to see that filters have been applied

It would also be helpful to let users know that multiple filters have been applied and could be affecting the number of results they're seeing. A notification box that appeared when a certain number of fields have been selected, and gave the user an easy option to start over by clearing all filters, would do the trick.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftRoKO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Your suggestions are very good. The first one is already  present in our framework and is very useful. The second one I will implement to make the users happy :)